# Grails each tag with iteration

Tags: grails, tags, iterator, each

Hey. How can i have a variable in each tag to be an iterator (for example, first time run cycle takes value=1, second time value=2, and so on..

Answer (score 11):

The status attribute is what you are looking for. See below:

```
<g:each collection=${books} var="abook" status="i">
    ${i}
</g:each>
```

if you call ${i} inside the each tag it will return the current iteration count.

Assuming the books collection contains 5 books, the output will be:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: ok thank you. What if i need it to start in any given number (for example=5)? I cannot use i+1 because it will mess with each cycle

Comment: What will mess where? If you just use ${i+5}, `i` won't be modified.